# Traducción para "herding cats"

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, idiomático

["Herding cats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herding_cats) es una expresión que se usa para expresar lo difícil, caótico o frustrante de tratar de traer orden donde parece que las cosas no quieran tenerlo.

> "Herding Cats: a frustrating attempt to control or organize a class of entities which are uncontrollable or chaotic

"Herding" viene a significar "guiar" o hacer de pastor. Un pastor puede guiar ovejas o vacas con relativa facilidad pero hacer de "pastor de gatos" es una tarea casi imposible. Los gatos no obedecen para nada.

Una búsqueda rápida en google para ver si hay una traducción "aceptada" para esta expresión me muestra por ejemplo ["Poner orden en una jaula de grillos"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=herding%20cats). La parte de "poner orden" está clara, pero "jaula de grillos" aunque hace referencia a algo casi como un manicomio es una referencia poco clara. Si buscamos "Jaula de Grillos" en google la mayoría de referencias son a una película (posiblemente la película acuñó el término en español) no a una expresión coloquial o idiomática.

Hay una traducción mejor para "Herding Cats" que "poner orden en una jaula de grillos", "poner orden en el manicomio" o una traducción directa tipo "Pastorear/guiar gatos"?

Comment: No es respuesta porque me imagino que de cada región va a resultar una versión, pero en Colombia hablamos de "filar micos para una foto".

Comment: He oído y usado la expresión *pastorear gatos* en español con este significado. Por ejemplo: *Llevar un grupo de adolescentes al museo es como pastorear gatos*.

Comment: Por otro lado, la expresión *jaula de grillos* es muy usual en español y anterior a la película, denotando un lugar en el que reina el caos. Por ejemplo, si lees en un periódico que *el PSOE actual es una jaula de grillos*, se entiende perfectamente que el periodista opina que Pedro Sánchez tiene problemas para controlar el partido y evitar que se le desmanden los barones. Al menos en España la expresión es de uso general.

Comment: «Arar el mar» se sale de la metáfora animal, pero me parece que tiene la misma connotación (quizás más tirando hacia lo inútil del acto que hacia la resistencia —en esta caso pasiva— del objeto). Una vez oí que algo era «como meter un pulpo en una red(ecilla)» pero no sé cuán extendido está o si se entiende muy bien.

Comment: Mirando los otros comentarios me preguntaba que es "jaula de grillos" y acabo de ver que se refiere a la película "The birdcage". Esa película en latinoamérica fue conocida como "la jaula de las locas" por lo que creo que si buscas una expresión genérica, esa no es. (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birdcage)

Comment: Una jaula como en la frase creo es un _pajarera_ no un _manicomio_, aunque quiza hay algo en la relación. un [ejemplo](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/mdocs/copyright/es/sccr_ss_ge_13/sccr_ss_ge_13_3.doc) de uso moderno

Comment: Para cooperar con dichos parecidos pero parciales: en Chile le decimos _cumpleaño de monos_ al caos y _cabecear mojones_ a la actividad de ordenarlo o darle sentido.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers address the expression as Spanish sayings (*refranes*) which is technically different from idioms (*modismos*).

I can't think of any *modismo* in Spanish that represents what "herding cats" want to transmit but there are plenty *refranes* that represents the same feeling.

In Colombia colloquially sometimes we use.

- *Más difícil que cuadrar N micos para una foto.*

Translates:

- *More difficult than organizing N monkeys for a picture*.

Some people say 10, 15, or even 100 monkeys, it depends on how much emphasis you want to put in the sentence.

Another less vulgar expression is to use the word "monos" instead of "micos" to refer the monkeys.

Fair to say that in a formal environments such expression is not used.

Another expression came to my head, frequently used by my dad which is Bolivian.

- *Bulto (o costal) de anzuelos.*

Translates:

- *A fish hook bundle (or sack).*

To describe political situations very difficult to solve, probably because of something fishy.

- *El proceso de desmovilización es un costal de anzuelos.*

But sometimes also used to describe chaotic people.

- *Juanito es un bulto de anzuelos.*

This expression can be accepted in a formal environment.

Answer (score 2):

Ciertamente compleja una respuesta, porque hasta ahora no hay una que sea extendida a todos los países. Casi todas las aportadas no se entenderían o sonarían forzadas en España, por ejemplo. Hay que tener en cuenta que en México y otros países, como tienen más dominio del inglés y están más en contacto con él, "importan" más expresiones que acaban siendo anglicismos locales.

> Poner orden en una jaula de grillos

podría valer, aunque tiene más connotación de poner orden en el caos, no de "domar" a alguien o algo que, a causa de su naturaleza, es casi imposible conseguir.

> Pastorear gatos:

se entendería pero nadie usaría esa frase, suena a traducción. Si acaso

> Adiestrar gatos,

pero tampoco es una frase hecha o que la gente use.

La traducción más aproximada que se me ocurre es:

> **Domar demonios**

que sí la he oído. Pero sigue sin convencerme ninguna solución.

> Poner puertas al campo

puede ser otra aproximación, pero tiene otra connotación; intentar retener algo imposible de contener.

Espero que alguna te inspire.

Comment: De hecho, he oído "pastorear gatos" varias veces en México. No es tan cotidiano como decir "poner orden en una jaula de grillos" pero si se usa. Puede ser que 'pastorear gatos' viene importada de los EEUU...

Comment: Gracias, he ampliado mi respuesta en consecuencia.

Answer (score 0):

Poner orden en una jaula de grillos es muy similar. Trying to put order in a cage of crickets is chaotic as well, crickets won't stay put just like cats. The Colombian expression "(en)filar micos (monos o changos) para una foto" will have slightly better chances but will have similar results. También podrías usar "Llevar adolescentes al museo es como arrear gatos".

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay muchas expresiones para expresar esto, algunas groseras, otras un poco más amplias en su acepción.

"hacerle la p*** a un muerto" decíamos en la secundaria.

"arar el mar" como dijeron en los comentarios.

"pastorear gatos" nunca la oí en mi vida.

"como cenicero en moto" y "como bocina de avión" no implican el esfuerzo sino la mera futilidad.

Acá lo que necesitamos es una persona mayor. Generalmente son las que más expresiones idiomáticas tienen en su conocimiento :)

Answer (score 0):

En español a veces se habla de "un saco lleno de gatos" para describir una situación caótica, incontrolable. Tal vez podría aprovecharse ese modismo para hacer una traducción, por ejemplo "transportar un saco lleno de gatos" o algo parecido según el contexto donde se utilice la expresión original.

Answer (score -1):

Aunque también está en inglés y se puede  emplear en un contexto no necesariamente caótico, me decantaría por: *coger al toro por los cuernos*.

Esta frase se puede usar para motivar, poner orden, seriedad en o ser constante, ... ¿acaso es el toro un animal controlable?

[Take the bull by the horns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_bull_by_the_horns)

Comment: Excelente frase para expresar "enfrentar la situación" pero nada que ver con "herding cats" cuyo foco esta en la futilidad de la tarea y en su poca posibilidad de éxito.